HOMO/LUMO Orbital in sigmatropic rearrangement
In the $[3,3]$ sigmatropic rearangement, the orbital used for the reaction are the HOMO of both the $\pi$ and $\sigma$ bond. It forms a six-membered ring transition state.

Yet in the $\ce{[1,5]H}$ shift, the reaction use the HOMO of the $\ce{C-H} \, \, \, \sigma$ bond and the LUMO of the $\pi$ bond.

I'm confused when we need to use the HOMO and LUMO for the sigmatropic rearangement.
Ref: Clayden, J.; Greeves, N.; Warren, S. G. Organic Chemistry, 2nd ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford; New York, 2012. ISBN 978-0-19-927029-3
